# Extract filters and biases using caffe

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I want to extract filters and biases from my own caffemodel, (no need to visualize the feature) and I want to save them into `.mat` file for `MATLAB`.
I used `matcaffe` to do this issue:

My workaround:

```
addpath('/home/jensen810814/code/caffe/matlab/caffe/');
addpath('/home/jensen810814/code/caffe/examples/super_resolution/');
addpath('/home/jensen810814/code/caffe/examples/super_resolution/Model/');
caffe('init','deploy.prototxt','super_resolution_iter_1000.caffemodel');
caffe('forward',{});
weights = caffe('get_weights');
save('/home/jensen810814/code/caffe/examples/super_resolution/filter_data.mat','weights');
```

But some errors happened:

```
Error using caffe
Expected 3 arguments, got 2
Error in model (line 4)
caffe('init','supe_resolution_train_test.prototxt','super_resolution_iter_1000.caffemodel');
```

I dont know how to solve this problem.
Can anyone help me? please and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give an additional argument for `'init'` the phase name.
I believe in your case

```
 caffe('init',...
       'supe_resolution_train_test.prototxt',...
       'super_resolution_iter_1000.caffemodel',...
       'test');
```